# About running mysqldump command in centos

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

```
mysqldump -uroot -p'passwd' --database databasename > /home/www/test.com/test.sql
```

When I run command above, it have no problem.

But when I change the test.com folder, for example:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p'passwd' --database databasename > /home/www/test2.com/test.sql
```

It shows the error:

```
bash: /home/www/test2.com/test.sql: No such file or directory
```

The path was correct, why?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/www/test2.com
```

(Run it as a user which will dump the mysql so that it has write permissions too)

```
mysqldump -uroot -p'passwd' --database databasename > /home/www/test2.com/test.sql
```